# Visited nodes in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph like this:

```
START root=node(0) 
CREATE 
(Dark { name:"dark" }),(Colors { name:"colors" }),(Blue { name:"blue" }),
(Indigo { name:"indigo" }),(Red { name:"red" }),(Orange { name:"orange" }),
(LightOrange { name:"lightorange" }),(Tangerine { name:"tangerine" }),
Dark-[:CHILD]->Colors,Blue-[:CHILD]->Colors,Indigo-[:CHILD]->Blue,
Red-[:CHILD]->Colors,Orange-[:CHILD]->Red,LightOrange-[:CHILD]->Orange,
Tangerine-[:CHILD]->Orange
```

It's essentially a tree, with some connections in between the branches.

Hence given an input of "dark","tangerine" and "indigo", I can get the most recent common ancestor, like so:

```
START a=node(*), b=node(*),c=node(*) 
MATCH pa=a-[s:CHILD*]->x, pb=b-[s:CHILD*]->x,pc=c-[s:CHILD*]->x 
WHERE a.name = 'dark' AND b.name = 'tangerine' AND c.name = 'indigo' 
RETURN x 
ORDER BY length(pa+pb+pc) 
LIMIT 1
```

My question is, how do I get the nodes of the smallest set of tree branch(es), that can result in the ancestor? For example, the result for the above query can be "dark", "orange","red","colors","indigo".

Comment: Not sure I understand. Wouldn't it be "dark", "colors", "red", and maybe "blue"? Why "indigo" and "orange"?

Also, you might be interested in my earlier post: http://wes.skeweredrook.com/cypher-most-recent-common-ancestor/

Comment: Sorry I missed a relation there - there should also be a Indigo-[:CHILD]->Orange.  The graph I'm looking for looks like this: http://imgur.com/TSw385y .  I've also checked out your page Wes, and I'm planning to use Anormcypher as well :) So thanks.